# Why isn't my nav class expanding to 100% of the width?

Tags: html, css, dom, position

So I'm trying to understand why when I specify the width for my `.thenav` class it is not expanding to the entire width of the page.

I UNDERSTAND that it is taking the characteristics of the `.container` class, but I don't understand why and what is the solution seeing that i specified the width? PLEASE HELP!

Here is my picture of what's happening (I  attached an image of what's happening because the jsfiddle makes the div appear at 100% and it's not):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9Ryy.jpg

Here is my jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/CheckLife/yox7Ln1b/3/

Here's the code for reference:

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 id="box" onload="changed()"><image src="nbaone.png" width="40px" height="55px" class="nba">NBA Legends</h1>
    <div class="thenav" onload="changed()">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.nba.com"/>Home</a></li>
        <li onclick="changeP()"><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Players</a>
            <ul>
                <li onmouseover="slow()"><a href="#"/>T-Mac <img src="tmacw.png" width="25px" height="20px" class="tmacw"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#kobesec"/>Kobe</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"/>Kevin Durant</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"/>The Goat</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li onclick="slow()"><a href="#">News</a></li>
      </ul>         
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

header, nav, section, aside, footer, article {
    display: block;
}

body {
background-image: url(backwood.png);
width: 100%;
margin: auto;

}

.container {
    margin: 0px auto;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 1300px;
    height: 100%;
}

.header {
    background:linear-gradient(to right, #5092f4, #f29641);
    margin-top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

.header h1{
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #f4ca1f;
}
.tmacw {
    display:inline;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px;
    top: 5px;
}

.nba {
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.thenav {
    background-color: #7886a3;
    width: 100%;
    height: 85px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

                /* Style for the Nav Bar */


.thenav ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

}

.thenav ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 90px;

    text-align: center;
    border-right: 1px groove #141e38;
    position: relative;
}

.thenav ul li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 33px 10px;
}

.thenav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #47e586;
    transition: all 0.90s;
}

                                /*Dropdown Nav */

.thenav li ul li{
    background-color: #7886a3;
    border: 2px groove grey;
    border-radius: 4px;
    position: relative;
}

.thenav li ul li a {
padding: 8px;
text-align:left;
}

.thenav li ul li:nth-child(1)  a:hover {
    background-color: #F47575;

}

.thenav li ul li:nth-child(2)  a:hover {
    background-color: #f7d759 ;
}
.thenav li ul li a:hover{
    background-color: red;
}




.thenav ul li ul {
    display: none;
}
.thenav li:hover ul{
    position:absolute;

}
.thenav li:hover ul{
    display: block;
}

                    /* End of Dropdown */

.userlogin {
    font-size: 12px;
    top:2px;
    color: white;
}

input[type=text], input[type=password] {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 8px;
    height: 10px;
    padding: 3px 5px 3px 5px;
    color: 162354;
    }

                        /* Stats Button */
.stat input[type=button] {
    background-color: #6cd171;
    color: blue;
    border-radius: 6px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding: 2px 2px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}


.log[type=button] {
    background-color: white;
    color: #008cff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
    padding: 1px 2px 2px 2px;
    position: relative;
    left: 5px;
    top: 3px;

}
```

Comment: It's worth uploading your code snippets here as well as providing jsfiddle links.

Comment: @pineda yeah i know its just everytime i do i get an error! haha i know im such a newb, ive been doing this for like 3 weeks now and i cant put it down, thats why im constantly asking questions! Thanks though bro!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A child div that does not have absolute positioning and has a width of 100% (unnecessary if it's display is the default of `block`) will be set to it's containers width.  Your `div.container` has a `width` setting of 1300px and it is the parent element of `div.thenav`, therefore `div.thenav`'s width will also be 1300px.

You can either remove width on the container:

```
.container {
    margin: 0px auto;
    background-size: cover;
    /*width: 1300px;  remove this */
    height: 100%;
}
```

or:

Move `div.thenav` outside of `div.container` as in this code:
(https://jsfiddle.net/nod19rze/)

```
<div class="header">
  <h1 id="box" onload="changed()"><image src="nbaone.png" width="40px" height="55px" class="nba">NBA Legends</h1>
  <div class="thenav" onload="changed()">
    <!-- contents of thenav here -->
  </div>
    <div class="container">

  </div>
</div>
```

---

Comment: but i did that so i can apply that to my content section ....i thought if i specify a width it will use the specified attribute.

Comment: I see.  Thing is, your `.thenav` div is _inside_ `div.container` so it will respect the width of its parent.

Comment: yeah i understand that but why if i set a different width? i know what to do, i just don't get if i can apply rules to children elements in other containers and they don't respect the parents? so the only way is if i remove it?

Comment: OR set position of it to absolute (and thus remove it from normal page flow), OR move it outside of the container div like in the jsfiddle I provided.

Answer (score 0):

Either the container should be the first wrapper and then comes the header, which could solve the issue. I am not sure if this is what u need. Please check this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/estgLn1q/1/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
    </div>
</div>
```

Or if you want to maintain the same html structure, then remove `width:1300px` from '.container' which will cause the container to take the same width as of its parent.

Answer (score 0):

I would just move `#box` and `.thenav` out of `.container` and start that class after those elements.

```css
  * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

header,
nav,
section,
aside,
footer,
article {
  display: block;
}

body {
  background-image: url(backwood.png);
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

.container {
  margin: 0px auto;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 1300px;
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #5092f4, #f29641);
  margin-top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.header h1 {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #f4ca1f;
}

.tmacw {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px;
  top: 5px;
}

.nba {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.thenav {
  background-color: #7886a3;
  width: 100%;
  height: 85px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Style for the Nav Bar */

.thenav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.thenav ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 90px;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 1px groove #141e38;
  position: relative;
}

.thenav ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 33px 10px;
}

.thenav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #47e586;
  transition: all 0.90s;
}


/*Dropdown Nav */

.thenav li ul li {
  background-color: #7886a3;
  border: 2px groove grey;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
}

.thenav li ul li a {
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
}

.thenav li ul li:nth-child(1) a:hover {
  background-color: #F47575;
}

.thenav li ul li:nth-child(2) a:hover {
  background-color: #f7d759;
}

.thenav li ul li a:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.thenav ul li ul {
  display: none;
}

.thenav li:hover ul {
  position: absolute;
}

.thenav li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}


/* End of Dropdown */

.userlogin {
  font-size: 12px;
  top: 2px;
  color: white;
}

input[type=text],
input[type=password] {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 8px;
  height: 10px;
  padding: 3px 5px 3px 5px;
  color: 162354;
}


/* Stats Button */

.stat input[type=button] {
  background-color: #6cd171;
  color: blue;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: none;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 2px 2px;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

.log[type=button] {
  background-color: white;
  color: #008cff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: none;
  padding: 1px 2px 2px 2px;
  position: relative;
  left: 5px;
  top: 3px;
```

```html
<div class="header">

  <h1 id="box" onload="changed()"><image src="nbaone.png" width="40px" height="55px" class="nba">NBA Legends</h1>
  <div class="thenav" onload="changed()">

    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://www.nba.com" />Home</a>
      </li>
      <li onclick="changeP()"><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Players</a>
        <ul>
          <li onmouseover="slow()"><a href="#" />T-Mac <img src="tmacw.png" width="25px" height="20px" class="tmacw"></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#kobesec" />Kobe</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" />Kevin Durant</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" />The Goat</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li onclick="slow()"><a href="#">News</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhh i see, but if seeing that the div is still inside the header, will it respect the attributes and still fix its position to the top? @michael